# Why when performing an html post for radio input type with name "datetype" it does not post correctly

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In asp when I try and retreive the name from a request.form("datetype") it does not pick up the value it is an empty string?  But when I change the name it appears to work.

Does not work:

```
<h1>Select your Mood Date</h1>
<form method="post" action="viewer.asp">
    <input type="radio" name="datetype" value="HappyDate" /><strong>Happy Mood</strong><br />
    <input type="radio" name="datetype" value="SadDate" checked="checked" /><strong>Sad Mood</strong><br />
</form>
<br /><br />
```

This Works:

```
<h1>Select your Mood Date</h1>
<form method="post" action="viewer.asp">
    <input type="radio" name="MoodDate" value="HappyDate" /><strong>Happy Mood</strong><br />
    <input type="radio" name="MoodDate" value="SadDate" checked="checked" /><strong>Sad Mood</strong><br />
</form>
```

If this is a protected keyword in html, then are there other protected key words in html?  Maybe b/c it starts with "date" it causes problem during the post?

Comment: Try adding a regular `<input type="text" />` to your form. Type something in it, and see if asp can find it.

Comment: No its IE8 v 8.0.6001.18702 that screwing up here.  Its works in Google Chrome and Mozilla.  Definitely a head scratcher.  Maybe IE has some special reserved words or something?

Comment: Looks like Microsoft executives made the executive decision to turn functionality for input names to the whims of their Interns.  Anything that starts with date or DATE or probably any other SQL native type name is completely ignored by the IE8 form that receives it? Hopefully this is only IE8. Don't have time to research, but its good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You must place it into an array, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="datetype[]" value="HappyDate"/>
```

See the difference with the name, use `[]` to set it to an array.
This also works all other type of inputs with the same name.

Comment: That's a PHP limitation; it isn't necessary for ASP. (In fact, I think PHP is the only server-side technology that's incapable of making an array of same-named form elements automatically.)

Comment: HTML is different from asp and php. So the name should be alpha numeric and it has to start with a letter.  So datethype[] doesn't conform to to w3 organism.  However you could change it to work with your server side before it renders it like name="<%= myarray(i) %>.